# What's the difference between using super() on a Class inherited from python object and a Class inherited from another user-defined Class

Tags: python

What's the difference and problems involved in this curiosity:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
```

Than

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
```

Even if the first example is wrong, it works. I thought it could be a redundancy, but I heard that using super() in a class that's inherited from object is wrong, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `super(A, self).__init__()` is just fine; `object` has an `__init__` method too.

What would *not* work is trying to pass *arguments* to that method; `object.__init__()` takes no parameters. And for most methods *other* than `__init__`, `super()` in a class derived directly from `object` may also not work because `object` does not have the specific method you are trying to call.

Thus, using `super(class, self).__init__()` with anything other than an empty argument list requires more intimate knowledge of your class hierarchy, where any classes deriving directly from `object` should take care not to pass on arguments.

For any custom methods, `super(class, self).other_method` will most likely fail because `object` simply doesn't implement that method.

Comment: Martijin, thanks for the explanation and good intentions in helping.

Answer (score 1):

super(class. self) is how one interacts with what's called the MRO, or method resolution order.

A very important concept to grok. Here's Guido on MRO: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html?m=1